# Infinite groups with a finite class number

Tags: gr.group-theory

Are there finitely presented infinite groups with a finite class number?

Comment: Do you mean number of conjugacy classes?

Comment: This appears as a problem here: http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/~shpil/gworld/problems/probFP.html
(Assuming that the class number is the number of conjugacy classes)

Comment: According to Mark Sapir's answer to Derek Holt's question in http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/95/finite.conj, for each large prime p there exists a 2-generated infinite group of exponent p which has exactly p conjugacy classes (that's Theorem 41.2 in Olshansky, "Geometry of defining relations in groups"). 

Comment: @Benjamin Steinberg: yes! The class number is the number of conjugacy classes of a group.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denis Osin proved that there was a finitely generated infinite  group with exactly two (count'em) conjugacy classes, but I can't seem to find any statement as to the finiteness of the presentation. (see [this paper by Ashot Minasian](http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/54841/) for references and more results).

Comment: @Igor: Osin's group is infinitely presented, which is also true for Ivanov's examples cited above. No finitely presented examples are known and there are no methods which can produce such examples even "theoretically". It is quite possible that there are no finitely presented examples at all. 

Comment: @Mark: thanks! I think I first saw Denis' examples because such a group (if I remember correctly) would not have any finite-dimensional unitary representations, but I guess it is much easier to not have such representations than to have few conjugacy classes...

Comment: Finitely presented "monsters" are discussed on pages 3 and 4 here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3873.pdf 